# AWS Mechanical Turk with Multi Factor Authentication (MFA)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

We use [Multi Factor Authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/) to protect our accounts. We login via https://My_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/

We want to try Amazon Mechanical Turk, however, nobody can log in at https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/ to create accounts. IAM permissions are set up but we still get `AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister` when using the API to post hits.

Answer (score -1):

Mechanical Turk supports IAM in the Requester API, but does not support it in the Requester User Interface found at http://requester.mturk.com. That's probably the root cause of the first issue you're experiencing.

In terms of the MustRegister error you're seeing in Sandbox when you post HITs, I'd suggest you start by calling GetAccountBalance. It's a read-only method that takes no parameters, and removes the risk that you're having an error in publish or somewhere else in the process. In other words, it's an API call that should always "just work."

If that's not the issue, I'd confirm that the GetAccountBalance does actually work in the MTurk production environment (the endpoint at mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com).

If GetAccountBalance works in neither, this would suggest the IAM credentials are not setup correctly. The most important things to verify are that (a) you're actually using the right IAM access key and secret key, and (b) that the IAM account you're using has the correct policies attached. On (b), make sure that on the AWS IAM Policies page, you choose AmazonMechanicalTurkFullAccess or AmazonMechanicalTurkReadOnly. At the top of that page, you must choose Attach to ensure they're attached to the right account.

I hope that helps.